# Getting untrusted enterprise error with beta iOS app

Tags: support, ios-app

I wanted to try the latest SE iOS app beta on iOS 9 (13A4325c).

After downloading v 1.3.2.229 via mobile safari, this modal dialog casts shade upon stack developers:

[image: Untrusted Enterprise Developer]

Have I missed a certificate to install?

Comment: Let me guess, iOS 9?

Comment: Anyway, fix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30722883/ios9-untrusted-enterprise-developer-with-no-option-to-trust

Comment: @Pat cheers, your answer is full and detailed, I couldn't answer it better myself. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a new iOS 9 security feature. Enterprise signed apps that are not installed through MDM have a manual approval step required before the OS will launch the SE app that's signed for enterprise distribution instead of App Store distribution.

As proposed by the dialog, trust StackExchange to be a legit and trusted app provider.

- Open your *Settings*
- Go to *General*
- Go to *Profiles*, which can be found at the bottom of the page
- Tap on 'StackExchange Inc.'
- Tap on the *Trust* button

When the profile is selected:

> [image: profile selected]

Trusting the app:

> [image: trust dialog]

Comment: Yes - I was looking for the documentation on how this works - apparently the bugs in iOS 8 betas were causing this dialog to not be a) documented b) clear c) work for some people across builds of iOS.

Comment: I figured that with iOS8 it was too just easy to trust an enterprise app.  Making you go 5 screens deep without instructions will give you more time to question if it's a good idea.

Comment: For some unknown reasons, I don't have to trust it to install the app. The iPad has trusted it itself.

Comment: Have noticed that once too. Seems to be a specific situation and I am not sure why it happened either. @ooker

Comment: Maybe because I have it installed when it was iOS 8, not install it new in iOS 9?